# Find and replace text in files in all subdirectories

Tags: macos, perl, shell

On a Mac; I'm using Hazel to run a shell script, in order to find & replace text in `.txt` files in multiple subdirectories inside my Downloads folder.
My script.sh file lives somewhere else (`/Users/admin/Desktop`)

`script.sh` looks like this currently:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /Users/admin/Downloads/
perl -pi -w -e 's/OldText/NewText/g;' *.txt
```

It works, but doesn't look through all the subdirectories inside Downloads. How do I do that?

Comment: The same logic shown in the accepted answer shall be applied to invoking `perl` too.

Comment: investigate the use of `find` and `xargs` to feed the file names to perl

Answer (score 3):

Use [find](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?find) and [xargs](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?xargs)

Something similar to (NOT TESTED!):

```
find /Users/admin/Downloads/ -type f -print0 | xargs -0 perl -pi -w -e 's/OldText/NewText/g;'
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you would need `perl` in this case, and I'm not sure who Hazel is and why she would run your shell script, but since you've flagged your question `shell` and are obviously using `bash`, I'll provide a shell-only answer.  Note that this will work in other shells too, not just bash.

```
#!/bin/bash

find /Users/admin/Downloads/ -type f -name "*.txt" \
  -exec sed -i '' -e 's/OldText/NewText/g' {} \;
```

Note that this `find` command is split into two lines for easier readability.  It uses `sed` instead of `perl` because `sed` is smaller and likely faster, and is considered a standard shell tool whereas `perl` may not be found on all systems.

Note also that the exact syntax of the `sed` options I've used may depend on the implementation of sed that is on your system.

The `find` command works like this:

```
find [path ...] [command ...]
```

You can `man find` to see the details, but the command I've provided here does the following.

- Starts in `/Users/admin/Downloads/`
- `-type f` - Looks for things that are files (as opposed to directories or symlinks)
- `-name "*.txt"` - AND looks for things that match this filespec
- `-exec ...` - AND executes the following shell command, replacing `{}` with the filename that's been found.

Comment: Hm. This removed the complete content of all my files (with specified ending) in the directory.

Comment: @Ixx - I'd need to see your exact command line to be able to tell you why. Along with your operating system, and/or version of `sed`. Most likely, your sed script (or the RE in it) is incorrect. Please feel free to [ask a question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).

Comment: This removed complete content for my files too. 

sed -i '' 's/OldText/NewText/g' {} \;  (removing -ne) fixed it.

Comment: @NickLothian and @User .. wow, I can't believe that error has been there for 7 years. The issue was just the `-n`, which suppresses output, requiring lines to be printed explicitly. Yes, it's not required in this case. I have removed it.

Comment: @ghoti - excellent, thanks for the update. I found the answer useful!